# 2gb memory laptop and 32bit application development

Tags: windows, visual-studio, 32-bit, virtual-memory

I want to develop 32-bit windows application in 2 GB laptop.

In this case, is there a way i can use other memories such as secondary memory or memory cards as my virtual memory which will be act as main memory?

IDE for development is Visual studio.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app doesn't use the memory directly. It uses [virtual memory](http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/archive/2008/11/17/3155406.aspx). On a 32-bit Windows your app will have an address space of 2 GB by default and 3 GB if you configure it to be large address aware.

Windows will map the memory of your app to actual memory pages as needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't plug another RAM card into your laptop, then only thing you could do is increase size of [Virtual Memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory). In windows there is this [official guide](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/change-virtual-memory-size#1TC=windows-7):

> Open System by clicking the Start button Picture of the Start button, right-clicking Computer, and then clicking Properties.
>
> In the left pane, click Advanced system settings. Administrator permission required If you're prompted for an administrator password or confirmation, type the password or provide confirmation.
>
> On the Advanced tab, under Performance, click Settings.
>
> Click the Advanced tab, and then, under Virtual memory, click Change.
>
> Clear the Automatically manage paging file size for all drives check box.
>
> Under Drive [Volume Label], click the drive that contains the paging file you want to change.
>
> Click Custom size, type a new size in megabytes in the Initial size (MB) or Maximum size (MB) box, click Set, and then click OK.